# How to create a clone of a flash disk in windows?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, flash

I am looking for a simple tool to create a 'copy' of a flash disk (e.g. compact flash disk) I insert into a flash card reader on windows. I want to be able to

1. Create a copy of the full image of the flash card to a single file
2. Copy the image to another same-size flash disk in my flash card reader

I was looking for a program to do this, but I did not find any useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Googling "win dd".  DD is a flexible program for Unix which does this, and there appear to be a number of versions for Windows.  As a linux person I can't try any, but look [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windd/) and [here](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd)

Comment: Thanks, but these two tools are the one I found myself, none of them I am really happy with (as a Linux person myself). Let's see if other have other suggestions...